# User information does not get sent to database

Tags: php, html, authentication, registration

I am new at designing websites and I recently wanted to add login/registration forms to my website I have a database and have coded all of the forms but when I attempt to register I am unable to because my information is not added to the database. I have been working on this for a while any advice on how to better my forms and registration system would be more than helpful. Thanks in advance!

Here are my forms:

Registration:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include "dbConfig.php"; 
if (isset($_GET["op"]) == "login") {
    if (!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"]) { 
        die("You need to provide a username and password."); 
    } 
    // Create query 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `gd_database` " 
        ."WHERE `username`='".$_POST["username"]."' " 
        ."AND `password`=PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."') " 
        ."LIMIT 1"; 
    // Run query 
    $r = mysql_query($q); 
    if ( $obj = @mysql_fetch_object($r) ) { 
        // Login good, create session variables 
        $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id; 
        $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"]; 
        $_SESSION["valid_time"] = time(); 
        // Redirect to member page 
        Header("Location: members.php"); 
    } else { 
        // Login not successful 
        die("Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information."); 
    } 
} else { 
    echo "<form action=\"?op=login\" method=\"POST\">"; 
    echo "Username: <input name=\"username\" size=\"15\">"; 
    echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"8\">"; 
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">"; 
    echo "</form>"; 
} 
?>
```

Login:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include "dbConfig.php"; 
if (isset($_GET["op"]) == "login") { 
    if (!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"]) { 
        die("You need to provide a username and password."); 
    } 
    // Create query 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `gd_database` " 
        ."WHERE `username`='".$_POST["username"]."' " 
        ."AND `password`=PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."') " 
        ."LIMIT 1"; 
    // Run query 
    $r = mysql_query($q); 
    if ( $obj = @mysql_fetch_object($r) ) { 
        // Login good, create session variables 
        $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id; 
        $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"]; 
        $_SESSION["valid_time"] = time(); 
        // Redirect to member page 
        Header("Location: members.php"); 
    } else { 
        // Login not successful 
        die("Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information."); 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "<form action=\"?op=login\" method=\"POST\">"; 
    echo "Username: <input name=\"username\" size=\"15\">"; 
    echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"8\">"; 
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">"; 
    echo "</form>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`, not the deprecated `mysql_` functions, your registration and login code is the same (bad copy/paste?)

Comment: What's the difference between the two scripts? They look identical - and format your code, it takes 30 seconds

Comment: @MarcB: there are a lot of problems with this code, but may I ask that we maintain a respectful tone here? I think where coding feedback slides towards personal attacks, it'll harm the overall tone on Stack Overflow, and the well-meaning part (that you have spent your time advising someone) may end up wasted.

Comment: OP, two main problems in this code are (1) SQL injection and (2) storing passwords in plain text. For the latter problem, look at `password_hash()` to do this safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login and registration scripts are the same code and they assume that you already have an account are trying to verify the credentials. You'll need to insert the data from the form into the database with an INSERT statement before anything else. Right now, you're just checking for accounts in an empty table.

Look up some tutorials for registering users. [**Tutsplus**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/user-membership-with-php--net-1523) is nice.

Answer (score 0):

here is a code for registration

```
     register.php

    <?php       

        include ("dbConfig.php");

        if ( $_GET["op"] == "reg" )

        {

            $bInputFlag = false;

            foreach ( $_POST as $field )

            {

                if ($field == "")

                {

                    $bInputFlag = false;

                }

                else

                {

                    $bInputFlag = true;

                }

            }

            if ($bInputFlag == false)

            {

                die( "Problem with your registration info. "

                ."Please go back and try again.");

            }

            $q = "INSERT INTO `dbUsers` (`username`,`password`,`email`) "

            ."VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', "

            ."PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'), "

            ."'".$_POST["email"]."')";

            $r = mysql_query($q);

            if ( !mysql_insert_id() )

            {

                die("Error: User not added to database.");

            }

            else

            {

                Header("Location: register.php?op=thanks");

            }

        }

        elseif ( $_GET["op"] == "thanks" )

        {

            echo "<h2>Thankyou for registering!</h2>";

        }

        else

        {

            echo "<form action=\"?op=reg\" method=\"POST\">\n";

            echo "Username: <input name=\"username\" MAXLENGTH=\"16\"><br />\n";

            echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" MAXLENGTH=\"16
```

\">\n";

```
            echo "Email Address: <input name=\"email\" MAXLENGTH=\"25\"><br />\n";

            echo "<input type=\"submit\">\n";

            echo "</form>\n";

        }

    ?>
```

inorder to add data into your database you need to use a query INSERT.hope this code would help you in solving your problem.